# Read Word and PDF in python

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word, text-extraction

In a folder I have 10 PDF files and 5 Word files (doc, docx). I would like to know how I can create a table in python with two columns:

1. ID of the file
2. Text of the pdf or word

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For reading the PDFs, you can use the library: https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/

For docx, the library: https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt

By file ID, do you simply mean the filename? You can use the following code to fetch a list of files and folders in the current working folder:

```
import os

filelist = os.listdir()
```